# How do indie game developers make money?

Tags: game-industry

How exactly do they make money their money?  Do they go by a paid-per-copy system, or some other form of compensation?

Edit: To clarify, I just saw "Indie Game - The Movie" and was wondering how developers like Team Meat get compensated for every copy of the game they sell.  Do they get say, a dollar for every $10 copy?

Comment: This question is too broad and basic, but [there are a number of ways monotize your game](http://gdcvault.com/play/1015659/Realm-of-the-Counter-Intuitive) (see but does ROTMG make $$$? section)

Comment: If Team Meat is selling the game directly, they get $10 for every $10 sale sans processing fees. Where would you imagine that $9 would be going?

Comment: Yea, I was just curious as to exactly how much they got from the $10.  Not seeing anything specific on the subject on Google.

Comment: [Steam takes 30% of each copy sale](http://www.vg247.com/2012/07/25/notch-reiterates-why-minecraft-isnt-available-through-steam/), (Team Meat is on Steam). The [Apple App store also takes 30% of each sale](http://presspadapp.com/kbase/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/App-Store-Pricing-Matrix.html).

Comment: _It's not_.  Steam and the Apple App store give you visibility and accessibility you'll be hard-pressed to find elsewhere .. as well as basic protection with a key system.  Do you want sales or the [90% piracy rate](http://arstechnica.com/gaming/2008/11/acrying-shame-world-of-goo-piracy-rate-near-90/)?

Answer (score 6):

- **Sales**: Selling their game, per copy. Or selling the rights to their game.
- **Ads**: Advertisements placed in game, on their website, etc. Admob, Adsense, etc.
- **In-App purchases**: Mainly mobile apps, in app purchases can be character upgrades, xp bonuses, etc.
- **Dontations**: Releasing their game for free, and asking for donations. Dwarf fortress does this.
- **Subscriptions**: Recurring fees to play their game, typically in an online setting.
- **Their day job**: Many indie developers don't make money from their games. They have to work a *real* job to get paid.

Comment: :) I like everyone of these _except for ads_.  Ads are usually a way to force purchase, but I detest ad popover placement within serious games (like games that people actually developed for people's enjoyment rather than to pop money out of people). Now __product placement__ is a type of "ad" I have no problem with.

Comment: But is that a seriously viable option?  There has to be a certain lack of self-respect for a developer to allow popover ads in this "game experience" they are creating.

Comment: Viable, I think so. In the free versions of mobile games this is fairly common. Ads in the transition screens, main menu, etc. They don't have to be popover ads.

Comment: I know it's common. But I think it should be evaluated -- how much money do people make on ads really?  I consider it as more __nagscreening__ -- "a way to annoy users and make them purchase"

Comment: I would rather have some ads in games than pay for the game up front. And I would rather a developer gets some money for their work than release a game for free.

Comment: Well I'm all for the old shareware scheme -- "pay to unlock".  But those ads that cover like 1/8th of the screen just say "cheap"! to me.

Answer (score 0):

This question is too broad and basic, but [there are a number of ways monotize your game](http://gdcvault.com/play/1015659/Realm-of-the-Counter-Intuitive) (see but does ROTMG make $$$? section).

1) Sell it on your website / via Steam or in an appstore like the Apple App Store or Google Play

2) In-app purchases (managed by Apple App or Google Play)

The world of in-app purchases is huge.  And what you can sell depends on what kind of game it is .. is it a persistant MMO type world?  Then have permadeath and sell scrolls of resurrection in the store.  Is it a shooter?  Then sell the ability to "unlock" the better weapons.  The list goes on, what you can sell as in-app really depends on what your game about.